# Telling git that a number of files originate from one single file

Tags: git

I have a repo where one file was split into multiple others.

For example, say we had `abcd.txt`:

```
a
b
c
d
```

And it was split into `a.txt`:

```
a
```

`b.txt`:

```
b
```

etc.

However, when I `git blame a.txt`, it says that I wrote the entirety of the file, when actually the author of `abcd.txt` should be listed as the author. This is also throwing off my GitHub review page, because it looks like I've deleted a file and added 4 files, when I've actually just split up one file, which would be much simpler to review.

How do I now tell git that I've split this file into parts? How should I have done the split?

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of a fundamental design decision in `git`. **Git commits do not represent diffs**. A git commit represents a snapshot state of your repo (i.e. it does not track renames, file moves, file splits, file joins, etc).

In order to accurately "track" changes as they move between files you need to use a different commit diffing algorithm which depends on your git toolchain. Unfortunately most tooling available today sucks for that.

It is commonly accepted that the best thing to do is to look at the commit immediately before the commit that added `a.txt` (or the same commit if the `abcd.txt` delete happened in the same commit) to see where files' content originated from.

One strategy is to write an explanatory note in the commit's extended comment so users can see what happened, e.g. `git -m "Splitting up abcd.txt to a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt"`. I also recommend avoiding mixing file rename, split and join operations with other changes:

1. Make a commit with `abcd.txt` as it was.
2. Split `abcd.txt` into separate files (`a.txt`, `b.txt`, etc) in the same directory without making any other changes.
3. Commit
4. Move the separate files to their final directories

   - This is to avoid mixing a file split with a subsequent file move operation in the same commit
5. Commit

   - This is to avoid mixing a file move with a subsequent file edit operation in the same commit
6. Edit `a.txt`, `b.txt` etc as normal.
7. Commit